# Symfony2 Validation with conditions

Tags: php, validation, symfony

It looks like symfony tries to help you out a lot with Validation but I am a bit confused.  I have an Address object that looks like this

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="address")
 */
class Address {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @var int $id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="street1", type="string", nullable=true)
     * @var string $street1
     */
    private $street1;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="street2", type="string", nullable=true)
     * @var string $street2
     */
    private $street2;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="street3", type="string", nullable=true)
     * @var string $street3
     */
    private $street3;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="city", type="string", nullable=true)
     * @var string $city
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="state", type="string", nullable=true)
     * @var string $state
     */
    private $state;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="zip", type="integer", nullable=true)
     * @var integer $zip
     */
    private $zip;

    /**
     * @var AddressType
     * This is only used for previous addresses
     * @DoctrineAssert\Enum(entity="RLD\AppBundle\DBAL\AddressType")
     * @ORM\Column(name="address_type", type="AddressType", nullable=true)
     */
    private $addressType;
}
```

I am using this object twice.  Once for Current address and another time for previous address.  The problem is I only need the info for previous address if the user hasn't been in the current address for more than 5 years.  I suspect I am going to need to extend the class in order to get what I want working.  However even after extending I am not sure how to make conditional validation.

## The Question

How do you make conditional validation?

```
if(currentAddress < 5)
    validate previous address;
```

Anyone have ideas for this?  This form seems to carry a common theme across it that needs this functionality.  Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: How you can do the year control? Where is the field with the date? Usually i implements this kind of conditional validation with a [Callback validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) in conjunction with [Validation Groups](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups). Let me know if you need an example about it

Comment: @Matteo So can I use the Validation Group inside the Callback validator.  I have been looking at the callback and I think its what I need the only thing I don't know is how to tell it to use a specific set of validation parameters and Groups does seem to do that job.  I just cant figure out how to use them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the validation group for activate selectively the validation callback. As Example:

**Address Entity**

```
/**
 *
 * @Assert\Callback(methods={"validateCurrentAddress"}, groups={"currentAddress"})
 * @Assert\Callback(methods={"validatePreviousAddress"}, groups={"previousAddress"})
 */
class Address
{

    ....

        public function validatePreviousAddress(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
    {
        if (/* is not valid */)
        {
            $context->addViolationAt('/*your field*/','error.previous_address_invalid');
        }

    }

}
```

**CurrentAddressFormType**

```
class CurrentAddressFormType extends AbstractType
{

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class'=> 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Address',
            'validation_groups' => array('currentAddress')
        ));
    }
}
```

**PreviousAddressFormType**

```
class PreviousAddressFormType extends AbstractType
{

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class'=> 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Address',
            'validation_groups' => array('previousAddress')
        ));
    }
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

What about using Traits?

http://php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.traits.php

Define a trait for your default attributes and then create 2 classes:

- Class Address
- Class PreviousAddress

The class PreviousAddress has the addiotional attribute.

You can then validate via instanceof:

```
if ($object instanceof PreviousAddress) {
    // has type
}
```

Comment: I am not very familiar with Traits however I would rather use the framework if possible.  It seems like there would be a lot of overhead to get what you are talking about working in all the instances needed in this project.  However this seems like a reasonable option to fall back on.  Thank you!

Comment: You can also extend the class using Inheritance Strategies. But also you have to use instanceof

Comment: I am looking at [Callbacks](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) to accomplish this and then maybe using yml so I don't need to extend a class just for validation.